# Is $D=\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}$ an open or closed set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cauchy-integral-formula

My doubt arises from the Wikipedia page on the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), where the set $D=\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}$ is defined as an open set.

As it includes also its boundary points $|z-z_0|=r$, shouldn't it be defined a closed set? (while $D=\{z:|z-z_0|\lt r\}$ be an open set?)

Comment: Exactly *where* on that page it is written that that closed disk is an open set?

Comment: I think $D$ is never referred to as open. There are other places where $D$ comes up again, not necessarily as a closed set such as in the first paragraph of [Smooth functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Smooth_functions). But that is no longer the same $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José Carlos Santos made a comment instead of an answer, otherwise I would have flagged his response as correct. Indeed, D is never referred as a open set, but as a closed disk contained in the U open subset of the complex plane. My mistake.

Comment: Actually, what I did was to ask a question.